# Convert string to nested array object by splitting the string javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Convert dot notation strings to array objects,
Eg.,

```
let obj = { 'user-0-address-pincode': 665766, 'user-0-address-city': 'Chennai', 'user-1-address-pincode': 32432, 'user-1-address-city': 'Bangalore'};

// Expectation output will be
{
 user: [ 
   {
     address: {pincode: 665766, city: 'Chennai'}
   },
   {
     address: {pincode: 32432, city: 'Bangalore'}
   }
 ]
}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please share the code you did so far instead of giving just requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and `split` methods to create a function that will take your object with keys as paths and then based on those keys create nested structure.

```js
let obj = {
  'user-0-address-pincode': 665766,
  'user-0-address-city': 'Chennai',
  'user-1-address-pincode': 32432,
  'user-1-address-city': 'Bangalore'
};

function parse(data) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, k) => {
    k.split('-').reduce((a, e, i, arr) => {
      const next = arr[i + 1]
      if (!next) return a[e] = data[k]
      else return a[e] || (a[e] = (!isNaN(+next) ? [] : {}))
    }, r)

    return r;
  }, {})
}

const result = parse(obj)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this is what i need